# Programmatically invoking method chaining in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a simple method which needs to be chained depending on the list of dictionaries. Following is the example.

```
e = Example()
instance_copy = e.perform_action("A, "Good")
                 .perform_action("B", "Very Good")
                 .perform_action("C", "Poor")
```

Now, I want to automate this flow with the input given from dictionary

```
e = Example()
d = {'A': 'Good', 'B': 'Very Good', 'C': 'Poor', 'D': 'Very Poor'}

# chain methods using e.perform_action(k, v) from dict `d.items()` identical to above
```

How can I achieve this in python?

PS: Please ignore the class implementation but I am looking for the solution for method chaining that can be chained by infinite size (restricted to size of dict) programmatically.

Comment: Why does it need to be chained? Why not just put `e.perform_action(k, v)` in the loop?

Comment: How do you expect chaining to work when you don't return `self`?

Comment: What you are asking for does not make sense. You specify that the chained invocations are to be performed in the loop, but each iteration of the loop has access to only *one* `k`, `v` pair.  More generally, method chaining is a primarily *lexical* technique.  It provides for you to use a particular syntax for invoking several methods in a row.  By definition, there is no chaining if you do not use that syntax.

Comment: You could do something like `e = e.perform_action(k, v)` to do the chaining in the loop, but this assumes you `return self` instead of `return self.instance_value`. And now it isn't any different than just calling `e.perform_action(k, v)`.

Comment: I am using internally built in library so I don't have any ownership to modify the existing functionality. To simplify this, I am just trying to find a way to perform method chaining with a list of k:v in a dict.

Comment: @JohnBollinger To clarify further, I don't wanna invoke strictly using for-loop as it returns a list object. But, I was trying to articulate what I am trying to accomplish but poorly expressed using for-loop. My bad.

Comment: Again, even if the method were implemented to support chaining, why is it important to make use of that, instead of, say, looping over the dict entries and performing a (single) invocation of the method per iteration?

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I want to automate this flow with the input given from dictionary

The way to do that is to drop the method chaining.  Example:

```
instance_copy = e
for k, v in my_dict:
    instance_copy = instance_copy.perform_action(k, v)
```

Method chaining is inherently antithetical to the kind of data-driven program flow you seem to be describing.

Note well, however, that depending on your Python implementation and version, the iteration order of your dictionary may not be the same as the insertion order, so if the order of the various method implementations matters then you need to take control of that. To cover that all the way back to Python 2.7, as the question is tagged, you probably want a list instead of a dictionary.  For example:

```
e = Example()
param_lists = [('A', 'Good'), ('B', 'Very Good'), ('C', 'Poor'), ('D': 'Very Poor')]
instance_copy = e
for k, v in param_lists:
    instance_copy = instance_copy.perform_action(k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

```py
e = Example()
d = {'A': 'Good', 'B': 'Very Good', 'C': 'Poor', 'D': 'Very Poor'}
from functools import reduce
instance_copy = reduce(lambda acc, curr: acc.perform_action(*curr), d.items(), e)
```